# Explicitly parse part of R code in a script

Tags: r, parsing, syntax

My usecase is as follows:

- Display GUI to collect some R expressions
- Generate a single source file containing my simulation framework, intermixed with the R expressions provided by the user
- Allow the user to generate the single source file. If any of the expressions specified by the user contain errors (syntax or runtime), I want to display these in a user-friendly way.

In short, I want to do something as follows:

```
myExpression <- "3 * 5"
myExprParsed <- tryCatch( parse(myExpression), .... )
```

My question is very simple: does R have some construct like `\Q \E` in regex, fully quoting a text string from beginning to end ? It is not unlikely that myExpression will contain the `"` character, thereby introducing a syntax error. I do not want to write the text contents to a separate text file and use `source()`.

=Example=

```
myExpression <- " XXXXXXX "
```

where XXXXXX is `paste("my random value is ", runif(3))` would amount to

```
myExpression <- " paste("my random value is ", runif(3)) "
```

which would give a syntax error. I want something like

```
myExpression <- verbatim@   paste("my random value is ", runif(3))   @
```

Comment: Dont understand your question. What has a regex got to do with it? Why would having quotes input by your users be a problem? They're being stored in strings, which isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get some input from the user - you'd just be getting values from text boxes in your GUI, I guess. I'll use `scan`:

```
> dowhat = scan(what="")
1: x="hello world"
3: 
Read 2 items
```

We have quoted strings:

```
> dowhat
[1] "x=\"hello" "world\""
```

We can parse it:

```
> parse(text=dowhat)
expression(x="hello
world")
```

And there's a line break because scan() splits things by lines. Not really a problem, and fixable if you care.

Now let's actually run it:

```
> eval(parse(text=dowhat))
```

And now we should have an `x`:

```
> x
[1] "hello\nworld"
>
```

?

Comment: So I will have to import the code from somewhere: either user input, or a file, or ... (it seems that I cannot just enter blocks of code like I can in e.g. XML using [CDATA )