# Fwrite splits text in one cell into 2 columns while writing to text file

Tags: r, fwrite

I am writing dataframe to text file using fwrite in R.
 
In one of the columns, I have a text:

> "Jordan Toothbrush Adult No Type 1 Unit (B/W-Jordan GPBSet(T1
>   TooG2x5)1u )"

But I see that it splits the text in 2 different cells with the values as

> "Jordan Toothbrush Adult No Type 1 Unit (B/W-Jordan GPBSet(T1"

and

> "TooG2x5)1u )"

Can anyone help here ?

Comment: This is because R might be considering / as line ending or new line , i think removing "/" might do the trick for you . Or while writing specify the line break which ever you are using , comma or tab.

Comment: It does not split at '/'. Can you tell how can we specify line break ?

Comment: i think parse will help you. have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929504/explicitly-parse-part-of-r-code-in-a-script/12930779#12930779